# Resize positioned background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have span, and it's styles are represented below. My problem is, it was designed to fill 60px*60px span. But now, I have to make it to fill another span with 50px*50px size. But it can't work with background position, because if i change the background-size, all position slips away. So is there any way (css or javascript hack) to resize an image or a block element with bacground-image after the image has been drawn? I want to avoid rewriting all background positions (I've got classes for each icons like ".entertainment").

```
<span class="icon icon2 entertainment"></span>

span.icon2 {
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#wrapper span.icon.entertainment {
 background-position: -60px -360px;
}

#wrapper span.icon {
 background: url(https://teeg.hu/image/icon.png);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you change the size of an image its position is going to move because its dimensions are going to change. Why not just change the position?

Comment: I don't want to change the position, because i've got ~40 classes with all icons position, and i don't want to rewrite all of them.

Comment: Ah ok, lets hope someone has an answer then

Comment: Don't sure if I understand the question, sorry if this comment is silly, but... how to use another background image for that icon (icon2.jpg)?

Comment: That hasn't got another image, it's just another class with more style settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pure css solution.

There is a js solution. Resize the background (background-size) as you did, then for each element move the position with the difference between sizes / 2 (in your case 5px).

You don't rewrite the classes, just iterate through elements.

Note: This might become an extensive operation, it is better to rewrite classes, even though that is what you want to avoid (40 is not so much... at most 30 min - testing included).

Comment: Ok, the quick and dirty solution has won again... But it's consoling me, this is not the only problem. This whole page should be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've written some hack. I resized the background:

```
background-size: 100px 1550px;
```

and did it with jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
        $("span.icon2").each(function(index, value) {
            var pos = $(this).css("background-position").split(' ');
            var newPos = [];
            newPos[0] = parseInt(pos[0].replace("px", "")) / 60 * 50;
            newPos[1] = parseInt(pos[1].replace("px", "")) / 60 * 50;
            $(this).css("background-position", newPos[0] + "px " + newPos[1] + "px");
        });
    });
```